# CSS: Facebook Messages like layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, scrollable

I'm trying to create web layout similar to Facebook's Messages page with fixed height header and footer and flexible height main element.

Inside main element has to be:

1. div (100% height of main elem.) and scrollable when overflow
2. div (100% height of main elem. minus div below) and scrollable when overflow
3. div with fixed height below second one and at the bottom of main elem.

[image]

I created basic layout with flexbox but what about those divs?

Here is a pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJLOrL?editors=110

Sorry for english

```
enter code here
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not a freelance coding service.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't want to paste here some ambiguous code so I better created pen. I've tried wrap all divs in parent one and create "another flexbox inside flexbox" but without success. I'm quite newbie with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purely as an intellectual exercise...`flexbox`

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  background: PaleGoldenrod;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header,
footer {
  background: lightgrey;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}
main {
  flex: 1;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.col {
  flex: 0 0 45%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.colcontent {
  flex: 1;
  background: white;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.colfoot {
  background: green;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="colcontent">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="colcontent">
      </div>
      <div class="colfoot"></div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/rVbYoJ) with overflow

Comment: Thank you very much Paulie, exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Using `position`s in a cunning way, we can achieve this with IE 6 compatibilty.

**Snippet**

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; font-family: 'Segoe UI';}

body {padding: 45px 0;}

header, footer {position: fixed; padding: 10px; background-color: #999; text-align: center; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; height: 25px;}
footer {bottom: 0; top: auto;}

main {width: 100px; background-color: #ccc; height: 750px;}
.main {position: fixed; left: 100px; top: 45px; background-color: #ccf; bottom: 45px; right: 150px;}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main>Main</main>
<div class="main">DIV.Main</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```